# Optimized handling of tag (empty struct) function parameters

Tags: c++, arm, x86-64, calling-convention, abi

In some circumstances, we use tags to discriminate between functions. A tag is usually an empty struct:

```
struct Tag { };
```

Suppose that I have a function, which uses this tag:

```
void func(Tag, int a);
```

Now, let's call this function:

```
func(Tag(), 42);
```

And check out the resulting x86-64 disassembly, [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WHh7Xl):

```
mov     edi, 42
jmp     func(Tag, int)            # TAILCALL
```

It is fine, the tag gets completely optimized away: there is no register/stack space allocated for it.

But, if I check out other platforms, the tag has some presence.

On ARM, `r0` is used as the tag, and it gets zeroed (seems unnecessary):

```
mov     r1, #42
mov     r0, #0
b       func(Tag, int)
```

With MSVC,`ecx` is used as the tag, and it is "initialized" from the stack (again, seems unnecessary):

```
movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR $T1[rsp]
mov     edx, 42                             ; 0000002aH
jmp     void func(Tag,int)                 ; func
```

My question is: is there a tag technique, which is equally optimized on all these platforms?

---

Note: I don't find where the SysV ABI specifies that empty classes can be optimized away at parameter passing... (and even, the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) says: "Empty classes will be passed no differently from ordinary classes".)

Comment: You could specialize a template but I really dislike specializations since they have so many drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the basic problem here is that when generating the standalone version of a function, the compiler has to generate code that can be called by anyone from anywhere according to the respective calling convention. And when generating a call to a function without knowing its definition, all the compiler really knows is that this function expects to be called according to the calling convention. Based on that, it would seem that, unless the calling convention specifies that function parameters of empty type are removed, the compiler can't really optimize away parameters from function calls in general. Now, it may be technically legal for a C++ compiler to make up whatever calling convention it sees fit for a given function signature on the spot unless the function has non-C++ language linkage (e.g., an `extern "C"` function). But in practice, this would most likely not be all that simple. First of all, you then need an algorithm that can decide what the best calling convention for a given function signature looks like in general. And second, the ability to link code that was not necessarily all generated with exactly the same version of exactly the same compiler using exactly the same flags, while not required by the C++ standard, is probably relevant in practice. Function calling convention optimization is certainly not impossible. But I'm not aware of any C++ compiler that actually does it (when generating object code).

One possible solution would be to, e.g., use different names for the actual function implementations and have simple inline wrapper functions that translate calls with Tag types to the respective implementations:

```
struct TagA { };
struct TagB { };

inline void func(int a, TagA)
{
    void funcA(int a);
    funcA(a);
}

inline void func(int a, TagB)
{
    void funcB(int a);
    funcB(a);
}

void call() {
    func(42, TagA());
    func(42, TagB());
}
```

[try it out here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5IILERyAgGoAKk2ABBJRwDsPbToAiHAMx8ADBtnzFq9ft0Ojpixo6W8LBp8xKAbqh46EoAZiIsyBCeykykdpoAlO5ueslK6f6BwWERGlEsMUlmaRk5yHlMRa66xpbJnt4svgFBoeGR0Uqx8TxJdamWGZmtZTz5hS4l6aMQlZP9tW6WLcHITAwMEAkGrkNlEAAsXHFqmltVU20Rh8c95/Mpi1IJjNIArFKkLNLmn6jSAGF%2BPwlMIxBJtFwTLRPgQfs8XgBrOgATgAdCiDrRzCYAGwolG4gAcuJ0XDeRNeUgOnwAtnRzOYvvDSP8pJ9BCAmXCpL8XnBYEg0LSAA54BiYMgUCDCsUS4goZhsAD6cnCiNIIXFBElnIgACMWfrPExiABPaQw0jC2mYAoAeS8Ft5nywtNYwAlLPwxEwijwfkwnJdpEwAA8/SIdZbPtFMAwWd59cRTWaARhJFIrXI8PSs89GB6UMDeIw8PrOZAXqgRQQ8KgWMGALT2kwc0TiST0ADurAI9trAEkWCE2TCXgmpB9mSG2WGSU3cQclMglcAlBA1SxEdsILhCCRIdC4unReLJUfaNsgbx%2BLD4QkkSBoWi8SYjm8DkvaCi3uYv1SNKkPS2JMt8s7SByXKkDyfKkAKiAoKgZ7yuQlCyueCqmrSwBElwTJagwOrEHqhohsaLCpjG1rIbaDpOt6mDumwXohj6fp1oGwa/KGEbIFGmZWnGk48UmKbmumWDUTmebjoWbDFrepZJpWWysrW9aNtILZtkIHYSHQE7vJ84E8WyGgAEoALJKMAyDIEoRJolwG77kQxCXieyFyhe3AmFw14ljw94uo%2BpDIlwByvlw%2BG0FwOhxToZImOYxyTkBIGMjOZmQUI0GwQWCEQEK3mYWhMqlfKIB%2BMgIoisqfg/sqtC4sqYZLpq2q6pQZE8RRVH5jRtJ0f2DFsUxHqsTx7H%2BlxLLhpG0aDcJibluJaYZtJxC5jGE5FpwSkCCp8DVhpDacgA9Paxxgp2hlUtOpl/NI7XLrSgg1f4P5oi1rn4O5nlKKePkeX5JiBYdIV8i8CCYEwWAKmpEVRSYOgmG8kV4biLWfuYlLpSZLJslB3IPkZUhcHSDJgUTuUFWFgYkZpIAHEAA%3D%3D%3D)

Also, note that, while the compiler may generate the function calls like that in the initial object files, link-time optimizations may be able to get rid of unused parameters in the end. At least one major compiler even [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ltcg-link-time-code-generation?view=vs-2017) such behavior…

Comment: Yup, the x86-64 System V calling convention packs small structs into up-to-2 registers.  I hadn't realized that empty structs could use 0 registers, but that is consistent with the existing rules.  While Windows x64 has very strict arg -> register mappings to simplify variadic functions (every arg fills exactly one 8-byte arg-passing slot), so e.g. a `float` first arg in XMM0 still bumps the 2nd arg to `RDX` even if its the first integer arg.

Comment: clang will sort of optimize away passing args it knows the caller won't use, with `__attribute__((noinline))`.  I was playing around with https://godbolt.org/z/vur-oK to add enough args that there were no registers left for `Tag`, so see if it took a slot in memory, and noticed that clang only copies 16 bytes of uninitialized stack memory in `call()` before calling `func()`, and doesn't set up integers in registers.  gcc only does that much IPA when making a custom `.constprop` clone of the non-inline function, but attribute `noclone` disables that unnecessarily.